# How to return array byte wrapped by object on java spring REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, data-structures

i want to return array byte inside object on java spring rest.

my expected response object.

```
public class ResponseByteArray {
    private String fileName;
    private byte[] file;
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }   
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getDataByte", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadUImageGet() throws IOException {
        ResponseByteArray response = new ResponseByteArray();
        File fileImage = new File("D://images//download1.jpg");
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(fileImage.toPath());
        response.setFileName("testFile.jpg");
        response.setFile(fileContent);
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseByteArray>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

but i the response of rest API is json format and value of file is string encodeBase64 instead if byte[]. what is happend to the process ? Rest can not resturn byte[] inseide object ?:

```
{
    "fileName": "testFile.jpg",
    "file": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxIQEg8PEhIPFRIPDw8QEA8QDw8PEBAPFREWFhUVFRUYHSggGBolHRUVITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0NFQ8PFSsdFR0tLS0tKysrKy0tKy0tNy03LS0rKy0tLSsrKzc3LS0rLSsrKy0rKzctLTcrLSstNy0tK//AABEIAQMAwgMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAABBQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAAECBAUGB//EAD8QAAIBAgMFBQUGBQIHAQAAAAECAAMRBCExBRJBUWEGMnGBkRMiUqHRFGJyscHwQpKisuEjkxUXM3OC0vEH/8QAGQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwUE/8QAIBEBAQEAAwADAAMBAAAAAAAAABEBAgMSITFBEyJRB ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a good reason for returning file data as a content type of application/json rather than image/jpg?

Comment: Either you can decode the base64 encoded string and save the bytes. That shall also work or use Produces MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE

Comment: Presumably you're expecting "file": [ 10, 20, 255, 0, ... ]? That's less efficient than Base64.

Comment: In your case you can convert byte[] to int[]. Another way is to use custom JsonDeserializer.  You can read about it here https://www.rainerhahnekamp.com/en/spring-mvc-json-serialization/

Comment: But, Mark Bramnik, Write well, Are you realy need to write you own wrapper? If you will use standard HTTP protocol, this will can handled not only by your code, but rowser can be do it without any logic.

Comment: i want to return fileName along with byte[] of file. as i read base64 encoded string is larger in size than byte[].

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about Rest as a protocol, then it can return bynary stream in a sense that HTTP protocol can work with binary streams. Here is an example:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/images/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> get(@PathVariable String id) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(service.get(id), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

However if you're talking about REST as a protocol that returns JSON/XML (which is something that I assumed reading your question), then, in this sense: REST returns textual (not binary) data (because you assume it) in a form of JSON or maybe XML.

**In any case how do you represent a byte array as a textual data?**

One way is to encode it into String representation which is exactly what Base64 encoding does.

Note that if you check the size of byte array and compare it to the length of the string created by Base64 encoding you'll notice that Base64 has a pretty significant overhead.